# How to manually trigger onChange event without <Field> element?

Tags: redux-form

I have component that renders like this:

```
<MyComponent 
  prop1Value={1} 
  prop1OnChange={this.handleProp1Change}
  prop2Value={2} 
  prop2OnChange={this.handleProp2Change}
/>
```

So it contains two fields/values internally. How I can sync it with redux-form? `<Field>` component provides only one value/onChange pair...

Tried it like this:

```
// values comes from getFormValues(...)
<MyComponent 
  prop1Value={values.prop1} 
  prop1OnChange={this.context._reduxForm.change.bind(this.context._reduxForm, 'prop1')}
  prop2Value={values.prop2} 
  prop2OnChange={this.context._reduxForm.change.bind(this.context._reduxForm, 'prop1')}
/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to use `connect` to bind those actions.

```
import { change } from 'redux-form';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const ParentComponent = (props) => {
    return <div>
        <MyComponent propOneOnChange={props.change('formName', 'fieldName', 'fieldValue')} />
    </div>
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { change })(ParentComponent);
```